# "have access" vs. "get access"

Tags: word-difference

> Through the application, the user can select any element of the page by moving the mouse over it and (**get or have ?**) access to its static and dynamic information.

Is there any difference between *get access* and *have access*.

Comment: What's wrong with just plain "access"?

Comment: I think you can use either have or get in this sentence, without any difference in meaning.

Comment: @JMB because I think the user do something (moving the mouse, selecting ....) in order to have access or get access...

Comment: I'm just suggesting that you can avoid overcomplicating things by using a simple verb. (Arguably, that should be a third option in your question, and in my opinion, the best one.)

Comment: @JMB I got what you mean, and I also said why I avoided "access", because I thought we usually do something to reach (get) something (access). anyway I also agree "access" is better

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong using "get/have access to"; you can use either of the verbs in this sentence, without any semantic difference. But, as a matter of fact and as commented by JMB, when it comes to a computer system, you usually use the word access as a verb:

"......... and access its static and dynamic information".

Answer (score 1):

> Through the application, the user can select any element of the page by moving the mouse over it and (get or have ?) access to its static and dynamic information.

What the user is "getting" or "having" here is not *access* to information (he/she already has access), but the information itself.  The user may not realize he/she has access, but you are telling them they do and how to get the information.

It would be better to word it one of these ways.

> The user has access to an element's static and dynamic information at any time by selecting any element of the page and moving the mouse over it.
>
> The user can get an element's static and dynamic information at any time by selecting any element of the page and moving the mouse over it.

Comment: You mean seeing or checking properties of something is not the meaning of "access"? and I may say "*to check or to view its static and dynamic information*"?

Answer (score 0):

have access = it's more formal and use frequently as compare to "get access".
Also, the use of get/have access means that the person either used to have or doesn't have access to a specific folder or files which is why a permission was requested.